# Can I log PIC instrument time in a sim without a current medical or flight review?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging, flight-simulator

Just wondering if one is on land and in a simulator, if you need a current medical and flight review to train and log PIC time?

Answer (score 5):

You can log training time in a simulator but you can't log PIC time.

The rules on logging are in [14 CFR 61.51](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_151). There's no requirement anywhere that I can see to have a medical and/or flight review in order to log time.

Logging training time in a simulator is allowed by 61.51(h):

> (h) *Logging training time*. (1) A person may log training time when
>   that person receives training from an authorized instructor in an
>   aircraft, full flight simulator, flight training device, or aviation
>   training device.

But, you cannot log PIC time in a simulator. 61.51(e) says (emphasis mine):

> (e) Logging pilot-in-command **flight** time. (1) A sport,
>   recreational, private, commercial, or airline transport pilot may log
>   pilot in command **flight** time for flights-

That means, the only way to log PIC time is in an aircraft.

Answer (score 2):

You can fly a sim without a medical.  Nor do you need a BFR either.  61.58 only applies to operation of an aircraft.  Sims do not count.